# How to display a JSF success message

Tags: validation, jsf

I was wondering how you can add a "success" message on a JSF page when the submitted data in a h:form is valid. e.g. "record successfully inserted". I tried using FacesContext.addMessage(String clientId, String message), but the message gets displayed in the same h:messages box that displays error messages in case of invalid data, resulting in text with a red color. I wish not to use JavaScript Alerts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use different style class

```
h:messages  infoStyle="color:darkgreen" errorStyle="color:darkred"
```

When adding message
for success

```
FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, message, null);
```

for failure

```
FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, message,      null);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `null` as client ID to make it a global message and use the following in the view to display global messages only:

```
<h:messages globalOnly="true" />
```

Just put this somewhere below or above the form, depending on the functional requirement. If you're already using a `<h:messages/>` to display validation errors instead of `<h:message/>` for each input element, then you need to set `globalOnly="false"` on this one.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Your solution doesn't seem to be working though. The success message gets displayed in both h:messages boxes.

My code looks like

<h:form> ...
 <h:commandButton action="#{jongereController.AddJongere}" value="#{bundle.JongereInschrijven}" />
                <h:messages showDetail="false" showSummary="true" layout="table" styleClass="validationErrorBox"/>
                <h:messages globalOnly="true" styleClass="validationSuccesBox" />
</h:form>

Comment: Just set `globalOnly="false"` on the other :) See answer update.

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the message twice, the view looks like:

<h:form> ...
<h:messages globalOnly="true" styleClass="validationSuccesBox" />
            </h:form>
                            <h:messages globalOnly="false" layout="table" styleClass="validationErrorBox"/>

And the code : 

public String AddJongere() {
        jDao.insertJongere(currentJongere);
        ContextProvider.getFacesContext().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Jongere succesvol ingeschreven","Succesvol"));
        return null;
    }

What am I doing wrong?